# How to get entire svn commit message in window bat?

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, hook

I need get the SVN commit message in post-commit hook bat in Windows, so I do this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('"svnlook log %1 -r %2"') do @SET MSG=%%a
```

I test it, it's ok for most case.

but, when I input multiple lines in SVN commit message, the command can only get the last line of commit message, I think it's caused by the windows batch file limit.

How to get the entire commit message to bat variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR /F` operates over the lines in the input. Try Changing `@SET MSG=%%a` to `@SET MSG=!MSG! %%a`.

Comment: don't forget `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, then.

Comment: Thanks, setlocal enabledelayedexpansion is the key~

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type or format of the commit messages, it might be preferable to keep the newlines as well; this can be accomplished using this:

```
set newline=^


setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Note that the empty lines are required for the newline, and so is `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` (once, anywhere before using `!newline!`).

Now you can use this to concatenate the messages (skipping empty lines, btw) with a newline, and then trimming the first newline:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('"svnlook log %1 -r %2"') do @SET MSG=!MSG!!newline!%%a
@SET MSG=!MSG:~1!
```

Comment: +1, Nice but my exclamations marks are gone, all my log messages contains a "It works!" :-)

Comment: @jeb: I would change that to "It works on my machine!" :) Newlines vs. exclamation points, every scripting language has its quirks – I bet you know it is `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` which is responsible for the disappearing exclamation points.